# The garage I went to cannot get the wheel off my car

Tags: tires, bmw

I have a BMW with a flat tire, I took it to tire shop but we could not find the bolt nut, and he said he could not do anything. So I went to breakers yard, they had one and tried to get the tyre off, they could not because the nut has been put on too tight. They sent me to a garage, they tried to weld a bolt to try and undo the nut, but the weld just snapped, I still have the flat tyre.

What can I do now?

Comment: I don't know about getting the wheel off, but there's a product called Tire Jack that is sprayed into your wheel that simultaneously plugs the hole and inflates the wheel. It's useful in an emergency.

Answer (score 4):

Have the shop do whatever it takes to get the wheel off. Lug bolts are readily available and not too bad in price.

If it's a lug that requires a special key and decent mechanic should be able to remove it even without the key. Some shops will tell you that it may damage the wheel in the process but as long as they pay attention to what they're doing then it shouldn't hurt the rim at all, I get them off often with an air hammer it usually works well and only takes a few minutes.

If the head of the lug just broke off and it's just the threads sticking out then just have them replace the hub. Once they've heated it and cranked on it and most likely hit with a hammer there's really no telling what condition the assembly is going to be in once it's all put back together. A new one would be the best/safest route.

Answer (score 1):

At some point that wheel will need to come off (even if fix-a-flat works for now).  Find a good general repairs shop (just a tire shop is not likely to be "good enough") you trust.  They may have to do some cutting...  It may destroy the wheel and likely will damage some suspension parts.  The good news is that it can be taken care of.  The bad news is that it might get a little expensive (both labor AND all the replacement parts needed).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJUUyjJqk5A) let us know if it works.

Also order a new key if you can, in-case you ever need to take another wheel off.